# How to use selenium to navigate web pages with multiple drop downs and check boxes

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate a process to download data from a website. The code works if I run it step by step but if I run it all at once it fails. Giving the error

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I have got around this using time.sleep(x amount of time) but it still seems to fail intermittently. I am having trouble implementing implicit waits. Any help would be appreciated. Code below.

```
import selenium

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'path\to\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://map.sarig.sa.gov.au/")
browser.maximize_window()

browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('MapViewer'))
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="TourWidget"]/div[1]/span').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menuAllMapLayers"]/div[2]/p').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="238"]/li[1]/div/div/span[1]').click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="238"]/li[1]/div/div/span[1]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="238"]/li[3]/div/div/label/span').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="239"]/li[1]/div/div/span[1]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="239"]/li[3]/div/div/label/span').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="menuActiveLayers"]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="groupOptions238"]/span').click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="238"]/li[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/span').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="groupOptions239"]/span').click()
time.sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="239"]/li[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/span').click()
```

Comment: _I am having trouble implementing implicit waits_ Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ActionChains](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) and get access to `pause(3)` instead of using `sleep(3)` but it could also help to use [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html?highlight=wait#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait) and checking if your elements actually are "visible" rather than "present" (see [expected_conditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html?highlight=presence_of#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located))

It's a lot of dropdowns so maybe there are not visible all the time, but you can run these checks after doing a move_to_element() so it would actually be present.